How do I create a image and a text sliding effect
I have my html section as
            <section class="w3l-main-slider" id="home">

                <div class="banner-content">
                    <?php 
                    // Array to store banner URLs
                    $banners = [
                        './assets/images/banner1.jpeg',
                        './assets/images/banner2.jpeg',
                        './assets/images/banner3.jpeg',
                    ];
                    $banner_text = [
                        'Text1',
                        'Text2',
                        'Text3',                     
                        ];
                    
                    ?>
                    <div id="demo-1" 
                        data-zs-src='[<?php echo '"' . implode('","', $banners) . '"' ?>]' 
                        data-zs-overlay="dots">
                        <div class="demo-inner-content">
                        <h1 class="mt-1 home-title" style="color:white;">Some text</h1>
                        <center><a class="text-center btn btn-style mt-4" href="text.php">Book with     Us</a></center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>


and some imports as
        <!-- Template JavaScript -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/theme-change.js"></script>

        <!-- banner slick slider -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.zoomslider.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
        <!-- //banner slick slider -->


The banner images are sliding as expected but I want the text from the text array to slide too.
I am trying to map through the text array but it is not working as expected.

I would suggest making 'cards' that have the Image and associated text, and then slide the cards.


$(function() {
  var c = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    c = c - 800;
    if (c < (0 - (800 * $(".banner-content > div").length - 1))) {
      c = 0;
    }
    console.log("Moving " + c);
    $(".banner-content > div").eq(0).animate({
      marginLeft: c
    }, "fast");
  }, 5000);
});
.w3l-main-slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.banner-content {
  width: 2500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.banner-content>div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 800px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="w3l-main-slider" id="home">
  <div class="banner-content">
    <div id="demo-1">
      <div class="demo-inner-content" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/101');">
        <h1 class="mt-1 home-title" style="color:white;">Some text 1</h1>
        <center><a class="text-center btn btn-style mt-4" href="text.php">Book with Us</a></center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="demo-2">
      <div class="demo-inner-content" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/102')">
        <h1 class="mt-2 home-title" style="color:white;">Some text 2</h1>
        <center><a class="text-center btn btn-style mt-4" href="text.php">Book with Us</a></center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="demo-3">
      <div class="demo-inner-content" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/103')">
        <h1 class="mt-3 home-title" style="color:white;">Some text 3</h1>
        <center><a class="text-center btn btn-style mt-4" href="text.php">Book with Us</a></center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



